# Fastest way to mass-update the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

So I'm changing a lot of entries at once in a certain part of my program.
The code right now looks like this for each one:

```
foreach(newentry)
{
    oldentry = context.Users.Find(entry.userid);
    newentry.oldvalue = newvalue;
    context.Entry(oldentry).CurrentValues.SetValues(newentry);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, this ends up querying the database 300+ times and is killing my performance.
The only way I thought of is to pre-load the database, but I don't think this is the best way either.

```
var userlist = context.Users.ToList();
foreach(newentry in userlist)
{
    var original = entry;
    entry.originalvalue = newvalue;
    context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(newentry);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

I'm still accessing the database 300+ times, aren't I? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use straight ADO to do that.  I'd get the list of user ids, then use a table value parameter to do the mass update.

Here's a sample from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) MSDN article:

```
UPDATE dbo.Categories
SET Categories.CategoryName = ec.CategoryName
FROM dbo.Categories INNER JOIN @tvpEditedCategories AS ec
ON dbo.Categories.CategoryID = ec.CategoryID;
```

Answer (score 2):

The second way will once load all users, then "mass-update" all users when you call SaveChanges. It is far more efficient than the first version because it does not send 300 selects (just one bigger select).

It is the best you can do with raw EF without manual SQL. The performance of this might well be ok for you. You probably should measure how long it takes and decide if it is enough.

If you don't think it is fast enough you need to resort to a raw SQL solution (which surely has been described elsewhere on the web).